# Checking for boolean value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean, addeventlistener

I'm coding a simple game in pure Javascript and have the boolean which should tell me if I have two or one player (vs computer), but in both cases I get either two players to play or vs computer.

Here is the code:

```js
 var computer = true; // true should be default
 
 // Click listener to change the value
 twoPlayer.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // styling code
    computer = !computer;
 });
 
 
 if(computer == true) {
     // code
 } else {
     // code
 }
```

I haven't been working in pure JS till now, I read a lot of questions about `boolean` but nothing helps.

Comment: Are you sure your event listener is executing?

Comment: *"...but in both cases I get either two players to play or vs computer..."* Huh? That would seem to be the two possibilities.

Comment: As suggested by @I.Ahmed, add a `console.log` in your event listener.

Comment: Can you post console error if any.

Comment: @I.Ahmed I log it after changing the value and also when I reach the if statment, it's stays false but expected behaviour is not I one I get..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code really is as shown, `computer` will be `true` as of the check, because the check is done immediately; there's no possibility of the event handler having fired.

You'll need to check `computer` *later*, after the event may have fired, in order to see changes made to `computer` by your handler. You'd probably do that in response to another event, such as the user saying "start a game":

```js
var computer = true;
document.getElementById("twoPlayer").addEventListener("click", function() {
  computer = !computer;
  console.log("toggled to " + computer);
});

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (computer) {
    console.log("Start game against the computer");
  } else {
    console.log("Start two-player game");
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="twoPlayer" type="button" value="Toggle Two-Player Mode"> <input id="start" type="button" value="Start Game">
```

**But**, depending on what `twoPlayer` is, you may not need an event handler for it at all. If it's a checkbox, for instance, you can leave it to maintain its own state and just check that state when you need it:

```js
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var twoPlayer = document.getElementById("twoPlayer");
  if (twoPlayer.checked) {
    console.log("Start two-player game");
  } else {
    console.log("Start game against the computer");
  }
});
```

```html
<label>
  <input id="twoPlayer" type="checkbox"> Two player
</label>
<input id="start" type="button" value="Start Game">
```

---

Side note: There's no need for `== true` in your comparison, just `if (computer)` is sufficient (or if you're checking the negative, `if (!computer)`).

Comment: I added a button that starts the game, the computer mode used to set on load and that was the problem..Thank you!